# Formatting so that cell is colored differently if it matches any value in column A, or column B, or both?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have tried solving this myself for some time and it just isn't working for me.  It's a somewhat specific goal I have so I haven't had much success finding examples online, so I'm hoping for some direction on how best to approach this.  I'm hoping to find a solution that uses VBA.  I'm pretty new to VBA so bear with me please!

I am dealing with conditional background coloring based on matching cell values.  I have three variable-length columns: A, B and D.  Columns A and B are randomly selected subsets of the values that are in column D - so, the values in the different columns may match, but they probably won't be on the same row.

When a cell's value in column D matches that of a cell in column A, I want that cell's row from column D to column K to be colored blue.  Likewise, if the cell's value in column D matches a value in column B, I would like it colored red.  If a cell in column D matches a cell in both column A and B, I would like it colored purple.

Does that make sense?  How would you suggest I approach this?

Let me know if I need to clarify further.  I would greatly appreciate any help!

Using Excel 2013.

Comment: Share a sample of your Excel Sheet with data, and another of the desired result

Comment: how to treat duplicates? what's the conditions hierarchy? show examples

Comment: I've uploaded the worksheet in question here:  http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/590480/Book2.xlsx


Column D is the source column, columns A and B are the random subsets.  As far as special conditions like duplicates...there shouldn't ever be duplicates unless a Transect name is misstyped.  In such a scenario...a message box saying there is a duplicate and exiting the sub would work, though I can probably figure that part out myself.

Comment: I also already have error handling in place for if the Transect column is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not actually seen your file, since I am at work, but I guess your table looks like this:

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
|  1  |  3  |     |  1  |
|  3  |  5  |     |  2  |
|  2  |  4  |     |  3  |
|     |     |     |  4  |
|     |     |     |  5  |
```

I rather like simple formula based approaches for that, but I could give you a vba example too.

With this setup I propose to use VLOOKUP. You basically check, if the value is part of A, part of B and then you can do the rest with your conditional formatting.

So if additional columns are no problem, just use the lookup to generate a true or false answer (I apologise for formula mistakes, since I use a german excel version):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,A:A,1,False)))
```

This will tell you TRUE, if there is a value in ALL of column A, that is equal to D1. If you also use this formula for column B you can base your colorcoding for blue and red on these two.

For the purple color you just need to compare the other two results again with a simple `AND`

Hope that is clear enough and I have read your question right.

Kaz

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kazschuri!  There is one detail I didn't do a good job of explaining in the original question.  I am actually hoping to change the formatting not just on the cells themselves in Column D that match, but also in a series of columns ajacent to Column D which are part of the same table.

Comment: I tried added a table similar to your example to show you what I mean, but I'm not sure if I can do that in replies to answers.  Basically, to break it down again....Column A and B are both different subsets of Column D, which I think is clear to you.  Column C is empty.  Column D through Column K is a table of different characteristics, so I would actually like the entire row of D-K to be highlighted if and when something in column D matches something in columns A or B.   Hope that makes sense.  How would I use your formula to achieve that?

Comment: Bear with me here...I am far more familiar with doing things the complicated way, with VBA, than I am doing them the proper way with formulas, so I'm figuring this out...I was able to use your formula to conditionally format Cell D, but haven't figured out how to make the same formatting apply to the rest of the table so that all of columns D - K match (even though Columns N-K contain different types of values, so they would not be matching with columns A or B)

Comment: Edit: deleted comment, was having another issue briefly

Comment: I assume you have build a setup like this: |A|B|C|D|....|K|isA|isB|isBoth|
You can then format with cond. Formatting. Use a formula for the condition: =$L2 and the range for which this formatting is used, has to be =$C$2:$K$1111 just adjust the numbers to your table.

Comment: Do you rather want a VBA answer?

Comment: I managed to figure it out without needing the IsA IsB and IsBoth columns, using conditional formatting.  It isn't quite the same as your answer but heavily inspired by it.  I used the formula "=MATCH($D3,$A:$A, 0)" for red if it matches column A, =MATCH($D3,$B:$B, 0) for blue if it matches column B, then =AND=MATCH($D3,$A:$A, 0), MATCH($D3,$B:$B, 0)) for the third color if it matches both A and B.

Comment: I applied that to the whole row D through K, then just drug it down.  It isn't perfect since I have variable length lists so I had to drag it down to row 100 or so, but doesn't seem to be slowing things down TOO much.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Right, I forgot about Match .... What I prefer about extra columns is the obvious "code" there. In Spreadsheets with a lot of conditional formatting, it can sometimes get confusing, where the changes are coming from. Formulae in cells are easier for to browse then those in cond. formatting.
But you found an answer, thats great!

Comment: That's a very good point you make.  In my particular scenario I think I need to try to hide these sorts of things but that is something I will keep in mind for the future!